# Private Gaming VPN

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, vpn, bandwidth

My buddy moved to Korea for the military, and we play Star Wars: The old Republic together. While connecting to the servers he gets an okay ping, but since the game uses a lot of data streaming, when he moves around or fights things, it becomes unplayable.

Last night he used a free VPN with 100mb of free bandwidth, he obviously used that up quick, but it resolved his lag issues. He had about 400MS to that VPN, which isn't that great, but it didn't spike up to 18000ms like it does when he moves without the VPN.

I host a mumble server, that he connects to, and he gets 220MS connected to my mumble/server. So, the goal is to set up a VPN that he can connect to, and use unlimited bandwidth, to play the game with me.

#### What I'm using:

I have two Ubuntu 10.04 dedicated servers, which I can run a VPN server from. 
I also have a Windows 7 machine, but I'd really rather host it via my servers.

I tried using OpenVPN, but the install documentation, wasn't clear enough for me to use, so it didn't end up working. So, I'm back to step one. Which server software would be best, and which client software would pair with it?